# Android SmsManager freezes when I use SendTextMessage function

Tags: android

My Android app freezes when I send the function "SendTextMessage". My code looks like this:

```
    public void doIt(View target) {
    ProgressBar pb1 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    pb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tv1.setText("Sending Text...");
    SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sm.sendTextMessage("#########(censoreD)", null, "lol", null, null);
    tv1.setText("Message Sent.");
}
```

How can I fix this? Nothing is wrong with my main.xml:

```
<Button android:onClick="doIt" android:layout_width="200sp" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Send Messages" android:layout_x="62dip" android:layout_y="189dip"></Button>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess and say you dont have the right permission.

```
android.permission.SEND_SMS
```

All permissions available: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html